# What circuit should we organize for two bycicles A and B in order to minimize costs?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

> A wash society ensure, for home service, a service of transport of clothes from client houses to the society the wash-house $(H)$
>
> 1. At dawn, we know the client list.
> 2. At 6' a bicycle $(B1)$ pop out of the shed $(S)$, go looking for the first patient, bring it to $(H)$ then go looking for the next patient... After the last client, etc... After the last one, the bycicle go back to the shed.
> 3. To ensure the return of the clothes, another bicycle $(B2)$ drive the clothes home after washing them. After the last client, the bicycle come back to the shed.
>
> The operating cost is made of fixed cost and of a cost proportional to the distance driven. What circuits should we organize to minimze the costs?

To my mind, it's all the same for any bicycle. Any of them have to respect the planning because whatever the distance is, it is still a distance to drive next. But it seem to be a so easy answer I can't beleive it's the right one.

I'm trying to understand if the Moore-Djikirsta algorithm could help me but as far as the bicyle has to do the way back each time it reaches a client, I'm afraid it can't.

Thus I don't know if there is a best circuit.

Comment: What are *your* thoughts towards answering this question?

Comment: @Mike Pierce You're right, I've just edited my question. Actually I even try to build a function that would give the cost given the distance to drive... but it's all the same....

Comment: Anybody? An idea?